# Indexed Search Crawler Configuration - Typo3 6.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I've a custom database table. I want to index the records of the table by
language specific. I've created a crawler configuration named "customindex"
and created a Indexer Configuration named "Data Indexer".

In my website, there are two languages: 0 - Deutch (Default) and 1- English.

But in frontend I can see both Deutch and English records in default
language search. I've investigated with this and I saw a
configuration "tx_crawler.crawlerCfg". (
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/crawler/ExtCrawler/Configuration/PageTsconfigReference(txCrawlercrawlercfg)/Index.html).
And I don't understand the key parameter here "paramSets.[key]". What is
the "key" actually indicated here? Is it extension key or crawler
configuration name?

I wrote a Page TS config like this;

```
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets.key =
&tx_myext_myext[uid]=[_TABLE:tx_myext;_PID:22;_WHERE:AND
(sys_language_uid=0)]
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets.key {
   baseUrl         = http://www.example.com/
   cHash           = 1
   pidsOnly        = 22
   procInstrFilter = tx_indexedsearch_reindex
}

# A second tx_tour configuration for another language with language ID 1
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets.key =
&tx_myext_myext[uid]=[_TABLE:tx_myext;_PID:22;_WHERE:AND
(sys_language_uid=1)]&L=1
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets.key {
   baseUrl         = http://www.example.com/
   cHash           = 1
   pidsOnly        = 22
   procInstrFilter = tx_indexedsearch_reindex
}
```

But I don't know what is that "key" (tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets.key)
indicated here.

Can you guys please help me to find what is that "key" here?

Answer (score 0):

"Key" will be any variable name we need to use as crawler configuration.